# Why is a request through JavaScript from a browser to localhost not blocked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss, cross-site

[webui-aria2](https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2) is a tool that allows controlling aria2 (powerful download tool) through rpc methods from a browser.

Using http://ziahamza.github.io/webui-aria2/, one can control aria2, provided the application is launched with the `--enable-rpc` option. aria2 basically starts an HTTP server listening on `localhost:6800`.

Great but I am surprised that the browser (both webkit and gecko) allows a page hosted on github.io to make requests to localhost. How come it does? Isn’t this a serious vulnerability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests to `localhost` from `github.io` will be treated like any other cross origin request.

JavaScript embedded on the site can't read the data across origins unless either:

- Explicit permission is given with CORS *or*
- A hack such as JSONP is used

Presumably the server uses one of those techniques.

Comment: It cannot be CORS so it is JSONP. I read a good amount about JSONP and my conclusion is that any website can scan use my browser to scan my network and have it send the results back. Is it correct?

Comment: Only if it can guess the hostname or IP address and path name of a resource that will return a JSONP response.